# Custom Formatting A String Value For Text Label

Tags: ios, ios6, nsstring, string-formatting

In my project, I have a function that runs and spits out a 5 digit number into a label on my interface. The number can be a double or a float but I would like it to display like ###+##.##

Example Number 12345.67

Shown like 123+45.67

The output will always be a 5 digit number with decimals. I researched data formatting specifically number formatting but haven't come across anything specific for this case. This is where I change the number to a string and assign it to a label. Please help and thank you in advance for your time.

```
NSString *outputNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",numberHere];

_stationing.text = outputNumber;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways this could be done.

```
NSMutableString *outputNumber = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", numberHere] mutableCopy];
[outputNumber insertString:@"+" atIndex:outputNumber.length - 5];

_stationing.text = outputNumber;
```

Another:

```
int high = numberHere / 100;
float low = numberHere - (high * 100);
NSString *outputNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d+%.2f", high, low];
```

These approaches won't work well if the number is less than 100.

Comment: Good Answer, thank you. I chose the latter option bc it made sense to me better. I would mark it as answered but my rep isn't high enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

```
NSStirng *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",numberHere];

NSString *firstPart = [numberString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
NSString *secondPart [numberString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 5)];

NSString *outputString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@+%@", firstPart, secondPart];
```

If the number's format is not permanent, you should check the length first.

Comment: You need to use `%.2f` for the format to get the desired two decimal places.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I went with Maddy's answer bc it was a lil easier code to me.